# (Ruby on Rails) Displaying How Many Unedited Posts A User Has

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making a bloglike application in Ruby on Rails where posts are automatically generated every day and then the user edits the post to fill in their daily information (like a diary).

I'm working on making an admin dashboard which gives the admin an overview of all users. I have the following code which displays all users and gives the option to delete them.

_user.html.erb:

```
<li>
  <%= link_to user.name, user %>

  <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
    | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                  data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Then on my home page I have the following code which will display this list if the user is logged in as an admin:

```
<% if is_admin? %>

<h3>All Users</h3>
<ul class="users">
  <%= render @users %>
</ul>
```

When a post is created automatically it is given the status "new" and this status is removed once the post is edited. I want to display to the admin how many "new" posts a user has when they look at this overview.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show the number of all post with status 'new' per user you just need to select all posts with this status and count them. Selection depends on what you are using to store state:
If you are using AASM:

```
new_posts = user.posts.new #aasm gives you scopes for each state by default
```

If you are using your custom binary field:

```
new_posts = user.posts.where(is_new: true) #select all user's posts where is_new field is true
```

If you are using custom string field:

```
new_posts = user.posts.where(state: 'new') #select all user's posts where state field is 'new'
```

Then you have to count this posts:

```
new_posts.count
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query the following in your controller since you just want overview/count of posts fir each user:

```
@users = User.joins(:posts).where('posts.status' => 'new').select('users.id, count(users.posts.id) as new_posts_count').group('users.id')
```

Then in your view,

```
@users.each do |user|
  user.id #this will help you to link show page of the user with unedited posts
  user.new_posts_count #count of uedited posts for that user
end
```

For the user's unedited posts detail page you can have the follwing in controller.

```
def unedited_posts
  User.find(params[:id]).posts.unedited
end
```

and in posts model for scope,

```
unedited, -> {where(status: 'new')}
```